# How can I access Javascript from Dialog page in Google Developer Console?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

On Chrome, does anybody know how to allow the Google Developer Console to access the javascript file that is linked to an HTML page requested from a dialog page? In my website, all javascript files are easily accessed from a window that contains the HTML page, but when I open a dialog box that through JQuery will request an HTML page, the linked javascript file won't come up in the Console.

Here's how I launch a dialog box with HTML (link) embedded:

```
function load_dialog(link, title, width, height){

//Take care of the options first.
var options = {

    autoOpen: true,
    position: "top",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    title: title,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    show: {effect:"fade", duration:500},
    close: function (event, ui){
        dialog_box.dialog("destroy").remove();
    }
};

//Launch the dialog.
var dialog_box = $("<div></div>").load(link).dialog(options);
return false;
```

}

I should also add that it is possible to see the javascript linked to this HTML when I open the dialog box through a new window.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about this question because I asked myself exactly the same one.
I hope you mean you don't see it in the **Sources** tab because as andyb said it appears in the **Network** tab but there's no chance to debug the dynamically added file.

After some googling I stumbled upon a stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651655/debugging-dynamically-added-javascript-files) asking a similar question.

Here is what they came up with:

If you want to set a breakpoint just add `debugger;` in the line you want to have it.
If the whole file should be listed in the Sources tab you can add a

```
//@ sourceURL=myfile.js
//or 
//@ sourceURL=path/to/js/myfile.js
```

at the end of the file you load.

I also found a Chrome Developer Tools docs [entry](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-dynamic-javascript) which describes what you have to do. Unfortunately the demo is broken (errors appear in the console)

Comment: Ah, awesome! Thanks for the help here - that did it. I wish this was more apparent in the Chrome Developer Tools docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the [*Network*](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) tab which shows every resource loaded by the browser. At the bottom of the DevTools Console you can also select *Scripts* to filter out other resources.